# Insert new values in SQL like vlookup in Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, vlookup

I have table like this:

[image]

I want to create a new column like this:

[image]

If I use vlookup in Excel it will be like this:

```
[column branch_name] = vlookup(branch_cd;subbranch_cd:subranch_name;2,false)
```

How to fill `branch_name` with SQL?

I have tried to query like this

```
select 
    subbranch_cd,
    subbranch_name,
    branch_cd,
    (select subbranch_name 
     from branch a 
     inner join branch b on b.branch_cd = a.subbranch_cd)
from 
    branch
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: You really need to not say "it doesn't work", that is totally useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing the problem is because your query returns multiple rows which will not work when you use a query as a column like this. But really you probably just need to use a join. Something like this.

```
select b.subbranch_cd
    , b.subbranch_name
    , b.branch_cd
    , sb.subbranch_name 
from branch b
inner join branch sb on b.branch_cd = sb.subbranch_cd
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case , you only need join self then select branch_name .

> ```
> CREATE TABLE branch 
>   ([subbranch_cd] varchar(3), [subbranch_name] varchar(3), [branch_cd] varchar(3))
> ;
>   
> INSERT INTO branch 
>   ([subbranch_cd], [subbranch_name], [branch_cd])
> VALUES
>   ('id1', 'aaa', 'id1'),
>   ('id2', 'bbb', 'id2'),
>   ('id3', 'ccc', 'id1')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> select T1.subbranch_cd,
>     T1.subbranch_name,
>     T1.branch_cd,
>     T2.subbranch_name  as branch_name 
> from branch T1
> left join branch T2 on T1.branch_cd  = T2.subbranch_cd
> ```
>
> ```
> subbranch_cd | subbranch_name | branch_cd | branch_name
> :----------- | :------------- | :-------- | :----------
> id1          | aaa            | id1       | aaa        
> id2          | bbb            | id2       | bbb        
> id3          | ccc            | id1       | aaa
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=cd8609ca21a1854d403e5922955e715b)*